# Vimeo uploading Laravel giving -file_put_contents():Write of 207 bytes failed with errno=13 Permission denied

Tags: laravel, api, vimeo

// controller

```
    $file = $request->file('video');
    $uri = Vimeo::upload($file, [
        'name' => 'test',
        'description' => 'easy upload'
    ]);

    return $uri;
```

file_put_contents(): Write of 207 bytes failed with errno=13 Permission denied

Comment: according to viemo docs, did you enable upload access? https://developer.vimeo.com/api/guides/videos/upload

Comment: Yeah, enable upload access. @jack

Comment: "Permission denied": the account you are trying to use doesn't have access

Answer (score 1):

The process running the app needs write permission to the temp directory (defaults to /tmp) for TusUpload to work.

For Laravel `$request->file` to work, the process also needs write permission to the file directory (this defaults to public/uploads in the root directory of the app, but can be configured)